# Identical Android apps with different package names

Tags: java, android, eclipse

I have two Android apps that are identical except for the package name. This question has been asked before, and the recommendation was to refactor the package name as required, but I do not regard this as satisfactory. To my mind putting all the code in a source library would be preferable, but is there a better solution?

Answer (score 4):

Putting the shared code in a Library Project is the recommended approach. See http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/projects/projects-eclipse.html#SettingUpLibraryProject

Answer (score 1):

I take it the question is "How to I build both apps without duplication?"  An easy answer: have your build system perform the duplication and package alteration for you.  And one way to accomplish this even if you're used to letting Eclipse or ant handle everything in ways opaque to you:

1. make a temporary copy of your entire repository, with the original building only one of your apps.
2. make all the changes to the copy that will cause it to build your second app.
3. create a single .patch that expresses these changes.
4. have your build system perform step #1, apply the patch from step #3, and then reinvoke itself in the copy.  "have your build system" means, write a script, add a target to a makefile (even if you normally avoid makefiles), add a target to ant, extend Eclipse, whatever.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but it sounds more complicated than using a source library.